# How do I get a reference to "Microsoft.Web.Preview" to resolve?

Tags: ajax, modalpopupextender, validation

I'm trying to include a validator on a form launched by the ModalPopupExtender control found in the AJAX toolkit.  This is an ASP.Net 2.0 web application.

Several articles that show how to do this, include this reference:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Microsoft.Web.Preview"Name="PreviewScript.js" />
```

This is the article I've based my page on for testing.  http://usefulaspnet.blogspot.com/2007/03/modal-popup-with-textbox-and-validator.html

The problem I'm running into is that the file cannot be found when the page tryies to open.

1. Is there a better way to do what I want
2. Where can I find this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out #1 is the correct answer.

All I had to do was make sure that the validators in the popup all were in the same validation group.